# Alternative ways to access Amazon EC2 instance should sshd die?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, debian, archlinux, sshd

On a debian or ubuntu instance, autossh usually does the trick and on an arch instance, by adding the daemon name to the DAEMONS array in /etc/rc.conf file.

What if sshd still fails to autorestart despite this measure being taken (in the respective instances)?  How can I regain control of my instance if some how sshd fails to autostart after a reboot or for some reason sshd dies?

On linode.com, they provide something called LISH (reference - http://library.linode.com/troubleshooting/using-lish-the-linode-shell) which solves this particular problem for me.  Is there an equivalent on Amazon EC2?  I can't seem to find documents referring to such a feature/functionality - which I feel is really critical for remote management of servers.

Comment: If sshd dies, there's something very *very* wrong.  You should look into what the problem causing sshd to die is, rather than patching the problem by having it auto-restart.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.  I've had a problem with my insistence where I could access the database but unable to ssh or access the webserver(not sure at all what went wrong).

To resolve, I contacted tech support(via the support forums but I think you can do it via phone also), and they restarted my other services.  They ask for your approval to connect and they can assist with things like this.

Comment: Lostsoul: their support forums tech support is horrendous... I won't depend on that if it was a slightly more serious project.  In comparison, support tickets to linode is completely free and I always get a super fast response from linode techs.  This is one of the biggest bugbear I have with Amazon AWS.

Comment: Thats true.  You might be able to open tickets with them over the phone.  With my setup it isn't a big deal because I run multiple servers that are load balanced.  So when I notice a failure, I can just kill the instance and start a new one..or in that case wait for tech support to resolve it.

I think this is the power of EC2..to scale many servers very quickly.  If your just running one server, why not go with a different provider? You'll get better performance(I found other providers weren't limiting cpu as much) and cheaper.

Comment: wouldn't one be able to scale many servers/instances quickly on Linode.com too?  I am just curious what's the advantage of Amazon EC2 vis-a-vis a well known provider like Linode.com or even Rackspace (Slicehost).  What's your experience with running servers on these providers compared to running an EC2 instance?

Comment: I haven't used any of those providers.  I used go daddy before and they were okay.  They corrupted my site during a migration than blamed it on me, so I left but I did like their service before.  They had no idea how to limit my cpu usage so I was getting a lot more power than I did on ec2(ec2 has a feature that does cpu stealing when you use too much..it slows you down).  I think rackspace and ec2 are the most popular, I read of a lot of startups using both of those.